# When did Doc Brown (and family) go at the end of the third movie?

Tags: time-travel, back-to-the-future

In the third Back To The Future movie, near the very end, Marty asks Doctor Brown

> Hey, Doc...where ya going now? Back to the future?

to which Doc Brown responds with

> Nope. Already been there!

But Doctor Brown has also already been to the past. So when, then, did he and his family go to?

Comment: Well, there *WAS* the cartoon which came after the movies and continued the adventures of Doc Brown and fam.

Comment: Interesting.  I always thought that Doc was referring to the alternate future they visited in Back To The Future II.

Comment: @MikeB Don't you remember the flying train? I always though he got his train modified in the future.

Comment: @DavRob60 Ah yes.  Good point.

Comment: Isn't it obvious? He already was in the past and in the future; only one option remains: Back to the Present!

Comment: I always assumed he went 'another direction', along the lines of the ending of '[Mimsy were the Borogroves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mimsy_Were_the_Borogoves)', or Mark Clifton's '[Star Bright](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mark_Clifton#.22Star_Bright.22)'.  Basically, ditch this limited 'Past-now-future' concept, and go somewhere New. (Off the mobius strip, as they said in Star Bright.)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[There was a cartoon:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Back_to_the_Future_%28TV_series%29)

> Following the conclusion of Back to the Future Part III, "Doc" Brown
>   settled in 1991 in Hill Valley with his new wife Clara, their sons
>   Jules and Verne, and the family dog, Einstein. As with the films, time
>   travel was achieved through the use of a modified DeLorean, which had
>   apparently been replaced following the original's destruction at the
>   end of the trilogy. The new DeLorean had voice-activated "time
>   circuits" and can also travel instantaneously to different locations
>   in space and time, in addition to folding into a suitcase. The
>   characters also traveled through time using the steam engine time
>   machine Doc invented at the end of the third movie.

Answer (score 13):

http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0099088/faq#.2.1.6

> ... Judging by Doc's letter he sent to Marty at the end of BttF II, Doc was more than happy living in 1885. Keeping in mind, he wrote this letter BEFORE meeting Clara. So it stands to reason he would go back to where he was most happy and live with Clara and now his kids.
>   .
>   Another, more fanciful, theory is that Doc took his family to the moon. Doc and Clara had a short conversation in the movie where they discuss their favorite authors and the possibility of someday traveling to the moon, which leads to this being a possibility. While the idea that they're flying a train to the moon may seem ridiculous, keep in mind that a flying Delorean in part 1 seemed very far-fetched and fantastic too, until part 2 come along and explained it.

This sounds like pure speculation (crowd-sourced one, based on all the typos); but there's nothing more official. Some forums mention a rumor around the movie release that this scene and the line were inserted at the last moment with the express purpose of setting up for a possible BTTF4, but I couldn't find any corroboration of that mention.

Comment: To the moon? :)

Comment: @SachinShekhar - look at kids' names :)

Comment: As far as I remember, there were no plans to make the 4th part. In fact, there was initially no intention to make a sequel to the original film too, the flying car was just a joke. As the Zemeckis and Gale explained, they wouldn't have put Jennifer in the car if they had wanted to make a sequel, because without her they could easily send Marty and Doc on any adventure. But that's not the case, and Jennifer has to spend a lot of time in the unconscious state instead.

Comment: In the conversation they had about travelling to the moon they originaly used the word 'train' to describe the vehicle before settling on 'rocket' - therefore its not so ridiculous

Comment: The *express* purpose. lol